# LLVM clone function pass to different module

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm creating LLVM pass, loaded in opt as library, which takes function from hardcoded module and clones its function to the input module.

```
bool MyPass::runOnModule(llvm::Module &M)
{
  SMDiagnostic error;
  LLVMContext context;
  StringRef ImplAssembly = R"(
    define void @foo() {
      ret void
    }
  )";
  auto InjectedModule = parseAssemblyString(ImplAssembly, error, context);

  auto* ImplFunction = InjectedModule->getFunction("foo");
  auto DeclFunction = Function::Create(ImplFunction->getFunctionType(), ImplFunction->getLinkage(), "foo", M);

  VMap[ImplFunction] = DeclFunction;

  SmallVector<ReturnInst*, 8> Returns;
  CloneFunctionInto(DeclFunction, ImplFunction, VMap, false, Returns);
  return true;
}
```

Even though the pass successfully clones the function, opt throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS at LookupBucketFor function.

```
if (LLVM_LIKELY(KeyInfoT::isEqual(Val, ThisBucket->getFirst())))
```

I want to know, whether the way of cloning functions is correct. If it is, then find the reason behind the crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments, found, that after passing the existing context of M, instead of empty variable context, the pass finished its work successfully, i.e. I should have passed existing context instead of creating the new one.

```
bool MyPass::runOnModule(llvm::Module &M)
{
  SMDiagnostic error;
  StringRef ImplAssembly = R"(
    define void @foo() {
      ret void
    }
  )";
  auto InjectedModule = parseAssemblyString(ImplAssembly, error, M.getContext());

  auto* ImplFunction = InjectedModule->getFunction("foo");
  auto DeclFunction = Function::Create(ImplFunction->getFunctionType(), ImplFunction->getLinkage(), "foo", M);

  VMap[ImplFunction] = DeclFunction;

  SmallVector<ReturnInst*, 8> Returns;
  CloneFunctionInto(DeclFunction, ImplFunction, VMap, false, Returns);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: do you face some type and dep missiing problem?